# twitter bootstrap date picker not working

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have been extensively searching for the answer but i cant seem to find one that works. I am using Django 1.4, with twitter boostrap 2.0.4 and i am trying to use date picker (eyecon) with no success. When i click on the input box no date box shows up.

```
<div id="due_date">
        <input type="text" value="02/16/12" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="datepicker" >
</div>
```

At the end of my base.html i have (right before closing the body):

```
<script src="/site_media/js/jquery.script.js"></script>
<script src="/site_media/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Finally on me jquery.script.js i have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.datepicker').datepicker()});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have selected all elements who have the class "datepicker", while your input element definition does not have such a class but rather has datepicker as id attribute set.

Either select the id field `$("#datepicker")` or add a class ".datepicker" to your input field.

Comment: thanks it worked. i had been following examples that were exactly the  same way i put , so i don't understand why they did that.. but thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do this: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#datepicker').datepicker()});`

As you have set `id="datepicker"`

`'.'` is used for class and `'#'` is used for id